# What is this small green fruit called?

Tags: fruit, food-identification

[image]

I want to know what is this fruit called in English

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you have there are [almonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almond)...or "the fruit of the almond tree". [image]

Comment: I think in English we would specify that they are "green almonds", to distinguish from ripe ones.

Answer (score 4):

Those are called "green almonds".

Green almonds are the unripe fruit, shell, and nut of the almond tree. The word "almond" refers to only the ripe nut, contrary to what other answers say here.

Answer (score 1):

Almonds. If you leave them on the tree till they start to drop off on their own they should develope a nice tan coloured shell and can then be stored for some time once dry.

Answer (score 1):

What you’re asking is, I believe, called “Çağla” in Turkish.

Çağla can either be, as others said, green (unripe) almonds and also unripe apricots as well.